# Orocommerce composer install failed

Tags: node.js, npm, orocommerce

when i try to install community version of Orocommerce, but i whem excecute next command: `composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev` after few minutes process stop and return next error:

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd <MY_PATH>/orocommerce/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/juan/.npm/_logs/2021-09-06T18_15_52_689Z-debug.log
Script Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets handling the install-assets event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to install npm assets
```

When i check logs, i found next trace (I dont know about node logs):

```
4506 timing build:run:postinstall:node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js Completed in 47ms
4507 info run node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall { code: 1, signal: null }
4508 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 2661ms
4509 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
4510 timing command:ci Completed in 118661ms
4511 verbose stack Error: command failed
4511 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
4511 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
4511 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
4511 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
4512 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.14.1
4513 verbose cwd <MY_PATH>/orocommerce
4514 verbose Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
4515 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "ci" "--loglevel" "error"
4516 verbose node v16.8.0
4517 verbose npm  v7.21.0
4518 error code 1
4519 error path <MY_PATH>/orocommerce/node_modules/node-sass
4520 error command failed
4521 error command sh -c node scripts/build.js
4522 error Building: /usr/local/bin/node <MY_PATH>/orocommerce/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
4522 error make: Entering directory '<MY_PATH>/orocommerce/node_modules/node-sass/build'
4522 error   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/home/juan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/include/node -I/home/juan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/src -I/home/juan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/config -I/home/juan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/home/juan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/uv/include -I/home/juan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/zlib -I/home/juan/.node-gyp/16.8.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
...
```

End of excecution:

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Y verify that all system requeriments are ok, and folders have correctly permissions. I download project without change anything.

Comment: Please run `npm ci` and share the output.

Comment: output its biggest:

https://pastebin.com/RPZn25Gt

Comment: It turned out the application is not compatible with NodeJS v16 yet. We recommend downgrading to v14 LTS till the bug is fixed

Comment: Its working, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, the error happens for having Node 16. With NodeJs 14.0 working orocommerce 4.1.1!